# Default Value or Binding Property in SQL Server Express not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, binding

I almost done my code, but i have a problem with default value or binding in SQL.

Here is my database :

- *Date_Contact DateTime* (with default value of `getdate()`)
- `Readed, Status bit` (with default value of `0`)

All of them are nullable.

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnSendMess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
        ContactUs contact_us = new ContactUs();
        contact_us.FullName = txtName.Text;
        contact_us.Email = txtEmail.Text;
        contact_us.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        contact_us.Message = memoMess.Text;
        db.ContactUs.InsertOnSubmit(contact_us);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        lblNotice.Text = "Your message sent successfully! Thank you";
    }
    catch (Exception) {
        Response.Write("Error! Check your message again");
    }
}
```

When I check in database, `Date_Contact`, `Readed` and `Status` are `NULL`... what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Where's the class where you define the two fields in question?

Comment: @GeorgeJohnston i'm using LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the object you are inserting into DB already contains values for these columns. Even though they are both set to null, it is still absolutely valid values from DB point of view, that is why nulls are inserted ignoring settings for defaults.

To resolve this mark these properties as Auto Generated (either set the corresponding property in LINQ model designer, or add Column attribute parameter `IsDbGenerated=true`).